# htaccess redirect not working on src folder

Tags: php, redirect

UPDATE: This is working very well. I just needed to put my SRC folder inside the public folder.

I've asked a Q about this before but it's not working well.

I have a folder called "listing"

Inside the folder, I have two other main folders called "public" and "src".

Like this...

```
<pre>
    public -> some index.php + other pages and files here. 
</pre>
<pre>
    src -> some backend files and logic here. 
</pre>
```

I want to redirect both the `public`  and the `src` folder to the root directory

So when a user visits the website, instead of localhost/public/index.php, they'll see index.php

I have created the .htacess file and added the following codes to it

```
RewriteBase /listing/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

But as you can see, the redirect is only pointing to the public folder. Any way to add the src folder, please? I'm tired of searching lol.

Comment: Redirects such as this are intended to help/stop people from using bad/old links. Is your system actually linking to `/public/` or `/src/` in the first place? If so, fix those links at the HTML level. Further, if those are-code only things that people shouldn't be able to browse to, consider moving them outside of the web folder completely and into an adjacent folder, or consider moving the web root to be a sibling of these. This pattern is very common in most modern frameworks.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the reply. I've some files in the src folder like the user account dashboard and admin panel. So I'll like to point to these files from the public folder. But I also want to make sure the .htacess rewrite them so they all look like a single web URL: exampl.com/user/dashboard.php instead of example.com/src/users/dashboard.php

Comment: @RohitGupta thanks for your reply. I'm trying to link my src and public files to the root index so it doesn't add the folder name to the URL. So instead of exapmple.com/src/users/dashboard.php, it should show example.com/users/dashbord.php

Comment: The over-all concept of `public/` is that public is the root directory of what the web server makes available to the public. If you have your app’s scripts in `src/`, you do not want them to be publicly available; that’s a huge security risk. If for some reason you want to make something in `src/` available, do so via your application.

Comment: @TimMorton, I would agree that in all modern frameworks `public` and `src` are used that way, but based on the OP's comments I'm not 100% certain they are using that way. Maybe the OP can clarify? Specifically, are there files in `src` that users can access via a URL. And we're not talking through includes, but can/should they be accessible via direct URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still unclear to me what you are asking.  If it is to map the **src** the same way **public** is working already, then surely you just add these lines to the end

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /src/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!src/).*)$ src/$1 [L,NC]
```

Personally, I would just shift the files, unless there is an undisclosed reason for it.  If you need them in both places then I would use a symbolic link.